# How to render specific VR camera in a unity scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

I am building a project in which multiple users will be able to join the same scene. I am using [VRTK](https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/) and whenever a user opens a project, VR camera will be initialized and the user will have public boolean variable called `isLocalPlayer` set to true for the local while other users will have it set to false.

My question is, how can I make the project ignore all other VR cameras for other users in which they have `isLocalPlayer` set to false?

I tried to set the `target eye` to None for the users that has `isLocalPlayer` set to false but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Any guidance would be appreciated